# I don't know if this is a shrub or a weed?

Tags: identification, plant-recommendations

Can anyone tell me if this plant is a weed?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On this site, we typically use the following definition:

> Weed:
>   Plant growing in a spot where the gardener doesn’t want it to.
>   Usually got there on its own.

Some plants have a tendency to spread rather quickly and *often* they get classified as weeds - because they take over the space intended for other plants. In my garden for example, forget-me-nots are on a mission of taking over the grounds, so I pull them up where I don’t want them and enjoy the unexpected blooms in others. All a question of preferences and gardening goals. Almost philosophical.

So it’s up to you to decide whether the plant in question is a weed to you or not, then act accordingly.

If you want an id, I recommend you check out the tag help for [identification](/questions/tagged/identification) and post a new question.

Comment: Thank you, Stephie, I did try to tag it as an Identification question, the website kept making me change the tag no matter what I used. I can't remember if I planted it, was hoping somebody might recognize it. Thank you for your reply.